# migrating a project from vtk5.10 to vtk 7.1 - missing headers

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, vtk, qt5.7

I am trying to migrate a project with Qt4.8.0 and vtk 5.10 to an updated version with Qt5.7 and vtk7.1 (in Visual Studio 2013).

I found out that many vtk files have changed through different versions. Is there an easy way to do the migration? The great problem I have so far is with the vtkSource header file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was quite a change from VTK 5 to VTK 6. I followed this [migration guide](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration_Guide). This pipeline re-architecture is met in many VTK examples by 
code like

```
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
  ...
#else
  ...
#endif
```